# Display .epub file with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, epub

I want to display an .epub (E Book file) in an iOS App. Is there a recommended way to do this with SwiftUI?

So far I have only found old information (mostly before 2016) here on stackoverflow and when I search for siwftUI + epub I get 0 results.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at any 3rd party frameworks? https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit for instance will get your started,

Comment: Yes I lloked into it, I hoped to fid a SwiftUI native way instead. Folio Reader has the problem that you must use a controller for it and as of the latest XCode relaease I got some compiller problems (but haven't had time to look into this yet).

Comment: You can mix and match SwiftUI with regular UIKit so it shouldn't be a problem. Good luck,

Comment: Ok, I got it working with Folio Reader with UIViewControllerRepresentable. Only promlem right now is that the FolioReader is not rendered inside the view, but seems to be an overlay.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: it's currently impossible to display ePub with some *SwiftUI classes*, but it is possible to show ePub in *SwiftUI project*.

ePub is quite complex format: it's a bunch of `.xhtml` files, `.css` stylesheets, OPF manifest file etc.

You may decide to parse it by yourself, or use some open-source parsers, e.g. https://github.com/stonezhl/Bookbinder

As `.xhtml` can be rendered adequately only in some web view, you can use `WKWebView` class.
As SwiftUI doesn't have WKWebView analogue yet, this can be done via `UIViewRepresentable`, e.g. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117348